# How to group values around a dynamic number of groups in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, sql-server-2012, grouping

I've read many/most of the posts regarding grouping in ranges but none seems to cover my dilemma, to group date according to a dynamic range of values, so I'm hoping someone can help or at least point me in the right direction.

Firstly, I have a set of ranges (but these can change and it would be normal to see between 2 and 9 rows in this set and of course the numbers would change too):

```
CREATE TABLE [Ranges] ([label] [varchar](160), [score] [int])

INSERT INTO [Ranges] ([label],[score]) VALUES('Red',    33)
INSERT INTO [Ranges] ([label],[score]) VALUES('Amber',  66)
INSERT INTO [Ranges] ([label],[score]) VALUES('Green', 100)
```

Then there is the actual data itself, which is stored in here:

```
CREATE TABLE [TableData] ([Name] varchar(160), [Value] int)
```

with the following values:

```
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Cat', 100)
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dog', 37)
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Bat', 16)
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Mole', 87)
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Hen', 55)
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dove', 28)
INSERT INTO [TableData] ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Rat', 6)
```

And the idea is to sort the [Ranges] data into a contiguous range, something like:

```
if value <= 33 then Red
if value > 33 and value <= 66 then Amber
if value > 66  and value <= 100 then Green
```

And plug that into a grouped query that would return the count of the [TableData] rows, in this case:

```
Red    Amber    Green
 3       2        2
```

But as I've said, I've no idea as to how to go about it dynamically, assuming it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

---

This is what I went with to get the max and min for each level. I haven't yet tested it on more than 3 entries for which it works. It will need to work on up to 9, as mentioned.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT cx.label AS label,
    -- when this one is the lowest one, go to the lowest in the range
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 cy.label 
                FROM Ranges cy 
                ORDER BY cy.score ASC) = cx.label 
            THEN 0

        WHEN cx.score > 0 AND cx.score < 100 
            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 cy.score + 1 
                    FROM Ranges cy
                    AND cy.score < cx.score 
                    ORDER BY cy.score ASC)

        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 cy.score + 1
                FROM Ranges cy
                AND cy.score <> cx.score 
                ORDER BY cy.score DESC) END AS scoreMin,

    cx.score AS scoreMax,
    cx.color
FROM Ranges cx
GROUP BY cx.label,
         cast(cx.score AS int),
         cx.color
ORDER BY cast(cx.score AS int) ASC
```

Using that, I inserted it into the selected option with the pivot and it works for 3 options, but I am still looking for a way of dynamically populating that list of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution 1

```
   DECLARE @Ranges TABLE ([label] [varchar](160), [scoreMin] [int], [scoreMax] [int]);

   INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Red',  0,  33)
   INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Amber',34, 66)
   INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Green',67, 100)


   DECLARE @TableData TABLE ([Name] varchar(160), [Value] int)

   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Cat', 100)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dog', 37)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Bat', 16)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Mole', 87)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Hen', 55)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dove', 28)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Rat', 6)

   SELECT * FROM 
   (
   SELECT
       R.label ,COUNT(*) AS CountRows
   FROM
       @TableData AS T
       INNER JOIN @Ranges AS R
           ON  T.Value >= R.scoreMin
           AND T.Value <= R.scoreMax
   GROUP BY R.label

   ) tmp 

   PIVOT (SUM(CountRows) FOR label IN ( Red, Amber, Green ) 
   ) AS pvt
```

Comment: I went with this one, thanks, but wrote a query to split the existing Ranges values into their own form of ScoreMin and ScoreMax. Something along the lines of:

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend to have both lower and upper bounds in the `Ranges` table.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Ranges TABLE ([label] [varchar](160), [scoreMin] [int], [scoreMax] [int]);

INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Red',  0,  33)
INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Amber',34, 66)
INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Green',67, 100)


DECLARE @TableData TABLE ([Name] varchar(160), [Value] int)

INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Cat', 100)
INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dog', 37)
INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Bat', 16)
INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Mole', 87)
INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Hen', 55)
INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dove', 28)
INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Rat', 6)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    R.label
    ,COUNT(*) AS CountRows
FROM
    @TableData AS T
    INNER JOIN @Ranges AS R
        ON  T.Value >= R.scoreMin
        AND T.Value <= R.scoreMax
GROUP BY R.label
ORDER BY R.label;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-----------+
| label | CountRows |
+-------+-----------+
| Amber |         2 |
| Green |         2 |
| Red   |         3 |
+-------+-----------+
```

If you want to get result set as one row with dynamic number of columns, then search for "dynamic pivot". Traditionally this kind of transformation is done on the client in the reporting subsystem.

Comment: This is 90% of the final solution, and I can't find a way of doing dynamic pivot without using dynamic SQL which would mean using a procedure rather than a query.

Comment: If you know that labels of your ranges are always `Red`, `Amber`, `Green`, then you can use static PIVOT and hard-code these values in the query as in the accepted answer. If these values are dynamic, then you'll need dynamic SQL. Or do the PIVOT on the client in the reporting subsystem. "Dynamic" SQL means that the SQL code of the query is generated by some code, that it is not static as in this or accepted answer. It doesn't have to be generated in stored procedure. Some code has to read the contents of the `Ranges` table and put a list of label values into the final SQL code of the query.

Comment: Right, as the labels vary, I did have to use dynamic SQL, but as I needed knowable column names I went this approach and created a view:

Answer (score 1):

solution 2

```
   DECLARE @Ranges TABLE ([label] [varchar](160), [scoreMin] [int], [scoreMax] [int]);

   INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Red',  0,  33)
   INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Amber',34, 66)
   INSERT INTO @Ranges ([label],[scoreMin],[scoreMax]) VALUES('Green',67, 100)


   DECLARE @TableData TABLE ([Name] varchar(160), [Value] int)

   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Cat', 100)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dog', 37)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Bat', 16)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Mole', 87)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Hen', 55)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Dove', 28)
   INSERT INTO @TableData ([Name],[value]) VALUES('Rat', 6)

   SELECT
       sum( case when r.label ='Red' then 1 else 0 end) Red,
       sum( case when r.label ='Amber' then 1 else 0 end) Amber,
       sum( case when r.label ='Green' then 1 else 0 end) Green
   FROM
       @TableData AS T
       INNER JOIN @Ranges AS R
           ON  T.Value >= R.scoreMin
           AND T.Value <= R.scoreMax
```

Comment: This option would have been useful for a fixed number of range rows, as it is, they are variable so it won't work without getting into dynamic SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I went with:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = ' Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4, Col_5, Col_6, Col_7, Col_8, Col_9 '

            --STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ColIdx) 
            --FROM RV_V_AuditCriteriaSetup
            --FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query =   'CREATE VIEW dbo.RV_V_ControlAuditRegisterCrossTab as 
                SELECT DISTINCT _registerID,
                                ' + @cols + '
                FROM (select _registerID, ColIdx, sum(CountRows) as countrows
                        from RV_V_RegisterAuditResults
                        group by _registerID, ColIDX) xx
                PIVOT (SUM(CountRows) FOR ColIDX IN (' + @cols + ')) AS pvt
                JOIN RV_controlaudit    ca 
                    ON pvt._registerID = ca.rid' 

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```